# PHP: Passing row values into form to edit

Tags: php, pdo

I have a table which is derived from a dbs table row values, echoing also an edit button for each row. On click on the edit button the user is lead to the edit form of the particular table row, in my case events. This is working fine, the user lands on the editevents.php page but I do not get the data to populate the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
        $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
        echo $eventid; *//echoing the eventid works fine so the parameter obvioulsy has been*
> passed through correctly via POST from the entry page*

        $stmt = $event->runQuery("SELECT event_name, event_description, event_category, event_date, event_venue, event_location FROM events WHERE event_id=:$eventid");
        $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The form:

```
    <div id="updateevent">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label>Event title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventname" value="<?php echo $row["event_name"]; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Description: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventdescription" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_description']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Category: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventcategory" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_category']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Venue: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventvenue" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['$event_venue']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Event date: </label>
        <input type="date" name="eventdate" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['event_date']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <label>Event location: </label>
        <input type="text" name="eventlocation" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['$event_location']; ?>"/><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update"
    </form>
    </div>
```

I do not get an error message and assume there is most likely a syntax problem as I am an absolute beginner, can somebody please give advice?

Update

Thanks @Mike, I was rather playing around with this on page bits of php to see how it works. I have this clean code which is intended to be the actual function outsourced in the class events file:

```
public function displayevent($event_name,$event_description,$event_category,$event_date,$event_venue,$event_location)
{
   try
   {

       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT event_name, event_description,  event_category, event_venue, event_location FROM events WHERE   event_id=$eventid"); 

       $stmt->bindparam('event_id'->$event_id);

       $stmt->execute(); 

       return $stmt; 
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }    
}
```

How can I call this from on page?

Comment: `<input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update"` that for one thing, is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing named parameters with variables. You are also not binding the variable to the query. Since you're not using raw PDO, it will obviously vary a little bit, but here's what you would do if you were. You'll just have to adapt it to your `$event` object:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT 
        event_name, 
        event_description, 
        event_category, 
        event_date,
        event_venue, 
        event_location 
    FROM 
        events 
    WHERE
        event_id=:eventid"
);
$stmt->execute(['eventid' => $eventid]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note: Cutting long lines short is also recommended.